# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of null

Tags: javascript, position, polygon, geojson

i have a drawing tool on maptalks 3D building and when i draw the polygon and wanna push newfeatures it will message the top error

```
var layer = new maptalks.VectorLayer('vector').addTo(map);

        var drawTool = new maptalks.DrawTool({
        mode: 'point',
        
      }).addTo(map).disable();

      drawTool.on('drawend', function (param) {
        console.log(param.geometry);
        layer.addGeometry(param.geometry);
        var lvl =  prompt("enter level building",0) ;
        //
        param.geometry._coordinates.position = ? <===
        alert(param.geometry._coordinates.position);

         var newFeature = 
         {
             id:"3"
             ,properties:{level:lvl}
             ,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:param.geometry._coordinates}
         };
         features.push(newFeature);       
        map.removeLayer(threeLayer);
        drawFeature(features);
      });

        var items = ['Polygon'].map(function (value) {
        return {
          item: value,
          click: function () {
            // threeLayer.addTo(map); 
            drawTool.setMode(value).enable();
          }
        };
      });
```

param.geometry._coordinates.position = ? <===(this line isn't in the code)
i think i should fill param.geometry._coordinates.position but i cant figure out with what

Comment: Is there a typo in your code? what is this `param.geometry._coordinates.position = ? <===` ?

Comment: param.geometry._coordinates.position = ? <=== what is this arrow ?

Comment: this is my question ,should i set value here?and if yes, which value?